# Will the Jetty web server instances share the same JVM?

Tags: linux, jetty, web-deployment

Good Morning .

If an existing Linux Machine is cloned to create an another Instance of it ,

Will it have same instance of the JVM ??

I was asking this question as when we do  a production deployment through a Linux script , it creates 5 wars of our code and deploys them into 5 instances 
of Jetty Web servers , and i observed that the  code is sharing the same JVM ??

How this is possible ??

I am using Jetty 8 and the Machines that holds Jetty servers are Ubuntu .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

different physical (or virtual) machines will have different jvm's

however it is possible to deploy multiple wars into one instance of jetty and have all those webapps running in the on jvm

it is also possible with jetty to start up multiple jetty servers inside of the same jvm

but jvm's are just processes of an operating system and 5 different instances of a linux install will not share a jvm across them

Answer (score 0):

Java 5 has an internal feature called [Class Data Sharing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/class-data-sharing.html). You can manually create dumps and use them. This stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692076/speed-up-application-start-by-adding-own-application-classes-to-classes-jsa) may help. If you want to improve startup time you may use [nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/). Nailgun is a JVM server for running Java programs from the command line without incurring the JVM startup overhead.