# Share in-memory object across multiple processes in the same machine

Tags: java, jvm

Is there a way to share an Object (without serializing) across multiple processes on the same machine? For example I have a Object of class Foo and I want this foo object to be shared across multiple instances of the same Java application. The problem is Foo is very complex object and is not serializable at all.

Like a `Map` shared across multiple Java/JVM processes.

Comment: There is no such a thing exists within java, you have to use some external tools, e.g. external cash, database or even file system

Comment: Google apparently patented a solution for object sharing across JVM processes: https://patents.google.com/patent/US6842759

Comment: Here's another hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13496725/785349