# What is the purpose of classlist file

Tags: java

Can someone please explain the purpose of "classlist" file and rt.jar files in java?

I need to figure out whether the particular project is shipping Swing Layout Extensions package or not.

Inside my project directory I see "swing" references in two places:

1. Inside `../jre/lib/classlist` file:
   javax/swing/JFrame
   javax/swing/WindowConstants
   javax/swing/RootPaneContainer
2. Inside rt.jar there are a number of swing classes

However inside my project there isn't any swing-layout.jar file.

So does that mean that the project is shipping Swing Layout packages or not?

Comment: This question would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692076/speed-up-application-start-by-adding-own-application-classes-to-classes-jsa

Comment: I think all those classes are mentioned inside the *project*. Though, if you are new in Java, why do you need to know this information?

Answer (score 3):

> To speed up the startup time of the JVM, the Sun developers decided it
>   is a good idea to precompile the standard runtime classes for a
>   platform during installation of the JVM. These precompiled classes can
>   be found e.g. at:
>
> $JAVA_HOME\jre\bin\client\classes.jsa

another one asked this question there 
: [Speed up application start by adding own application classes to classes.jsa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692076/speed-up-application-start-by-adding-own-application-classes-to-classes-jsa)

it will help you .

Comment: Partly copying another question and posting it as an answer doesn't help. you should have at least referred that thread.

Comment: i am trying to this already but iam logging in from my mobile and i can't update my answer .. !!